# 関西弁 「～せんと」- More than just「～しないと」?

Tags: kansai-ben

Following scene: Evil henchman grabs girl threatening her and asks her if she won't become his woman to which the girl reluctantly declines and says that she already has somebody in her life. The bad guy starts laughing and lets her go, shooing her away. Cue good guy:

> 読めねぇな・・・あんただけは

*You're the only one I can never predict.*

Bad guy responds:

> 俺は　正直モンが好きなだけや
> 人の顔色うかがったり**せんと**
> 俺がそうやからなぁ

*I just like honest people who don't care about the other party's feelings. I'm like that, y'know.*

In italics my translation. My question pertains to the bolded「せんと」. My initial thought was that this meant「～しないと（だめだ）」but that wouldn't make any sense in this context (*I like honest people. They gotta consider the other party too.*) I've googled this construction and found out that it can also mean「～しないで」or「～せず」. Given that, would I be correct to assume that the latter meaning here is intended and that the guys line is simply abbreviated - if I were to take a guess, the whole thing could go like this:「人の顔色うかがったりせんと［しないで］言いたいこと言うだけやから（正直な人が好き）」?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT：[The scene in question](https://youtu.be/gVOlbhDjsDQ), the relevant part starts at 21:55, the lines mentioned above occur at 23:15.

Comment: These three lines don't make much sense to me, either. Could you share the original page if this is a manga?

Comment: It's from a game actually, I edited my original post with the cutscene and a timestamp for when it occurs. If you have the time to check it out, I'd appreciate it. :)

Comment: I think your guess is right and it's something like "I like honest people. They don't care about other people's feelings. I'm like that too"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I watched the video clip but I'm still unsure about this. It's hard for me to interpret this as a pure Kansai-ben sentence. But I agree that this cannot be a conditional-と.

This may be "explanatory-と" used instead of の mainly in Kyushu dialects. For example, そうじゃなかと is そうじゃないんだ, and 彼は言わんと is 彼は言わないんだ in Kyushu-ben. Then the whole sentence would mean (正直モンは)人の顔色を伺ったりしないんだ, which would fit the context.

Looks like Majima is known as a person who speaks an unnatural Kansai-ben with wrong intonation (cf [真島弁](https://dengekionline.com/elem/000/000/145/145904/)). This is a hunch, but maybe the writer intentionally mixed a little Kyushu-ben to make his speech more unnatural?

Comment: I never thought about that possibility, I just saw some kansai-isms and instantly thought he spoke the dialect proper. Interesting how the VA for the character doesn't actually speak the dialect and they left it as its own thing. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Boolicious Actually the first thing I did after hearing his voice was to check his birthplace. The explanation for his strange Kansai-ben seems to have been added as an afterthought, but he is officially an [エセ関西弁](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%A8%E3%82%BB%E9%96%A2%E8%A5%BF%E5%BC%81) speaker now.